# Package 'cmake' has no installation candidate ubuntu 12.04

Tags: software-installation, cmake

When I run

```
sudo apt-get install cmake
```

I get the following response:

```
Package cmake is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'cmake' has no installation candidate
```

How do I install `cmake`?

Answer (score 14):

I faced the same problem and after googling a bit, I become able to install cmake. I fixed my problem as follow:

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cmake
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you enable the universe repository? Which version of Ubuntu?

Try this: https://launchpad.net/~kalakris/+archive/cmake.

It's a PPA with the newest `cmake`. I confirm to you that `cmake` exists and can be installed with:

```
apt-get install cmake
```

Answer (score 0):

I used command: "sudo apt-get install cmake-gui" and got error message as below

Package cmake-gui is a virtual package provided by:
  cmake3-qt-gui 3.5.1-1ubuntu3~14.04.1
  cmake-qt-gui 2.8.12.2-0ubuntu3
You should explicitly select one to install.

I then changed my command to "sudo apt-get install cmake-qt-qui" and it works.